# ArrayInput - How to set default value

Tags: react-admin

How do we set the default value for ArrayInput in react admin ?
I tried without success

```
<ArrayInput source="to" defaultValue={[{email: 'test@example.com'}]}>
    <SimpleFormIterator>
        <TextInput source="email" {...rest} />
    </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

Comment: There are some news! A PR has been merged about your issue, and will be published on `react-admin@2.2.0`. https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/2067
You can use the `next` branch to build your own version if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be correct.

I reproduced the issue in a CodeSandbox and I filled an issue for you:

- CodeSandbox: See the field `backlinks` in the `src/posts/PostCreate` file at https://codesandbox.io/s/1wqxkv6pml
- GitHub issue: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2046

EDIT: The issue has been resolved and is available on the version 2.2.0 as shown by the following sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/4z383v368x